# parsing a text from AppleScript

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript

I'm trying to get only one voice from the response of a script that I run inside AppleScript with

```
do shell script "<mycommand>"
```

Basically all I need is to store this `"Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n"` as a variable for later use.

Below is the full string I am receiving.

I think `awk` should be the solution, but unfortunately I had bad luck with it.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Below is the full string I'm receiving that's a report from a new entry created in firebase.

```
{"id":"Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n","data":{"spa_id":"0","os":"10.14.6","name":"Spa_Name","activity":"0","spa_email":"info@spa.com","serial":"C07XMRXWJYVW","nation":"Italy","spa_address":"Apliu Street 54, Hong Kong","ip_address":"192.168.2.1","global_unit_id":"0","city":"Perugia","branch":"Main","spa_unit_nr":"1","uid":"dev","spa_website":"www.spaname.com","continent":"Europe","spa_phone":"+852 3847569"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of the JSON values or keys were to contain a quotation mark. `"`, then using it as a delimiter to split the text with a tool such as `cut` would not work.  Likewise, a comma--which is another tempting character to consider as a potential delimiter--presents the same issue.  You also lose the key-value associations, which could be a handicap.

The script below should provide a more full-proof solution that works in more general situations, as it specifically caters to JSON strings, and converts them into native AppleScript data types (a `record`), so the key-value relationship is still there (albeit, unilateral).

```
set JSON to JSONStringToRecord from "{
    \"id\": \"Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n\",
    \"data\": {
        \"spa_id\": \"0\",
        \"os\": \"10.14.6\",
        \"name\": \"Spa_Name\",
        \"activity\": \"0\",
        \"spa_email\": \"info@spa.com\",
        \"serial\": \"C07XMRXWJYVW\",
        \"nation\": \"Italy\",
        \"spa_address\": \"Apliu Street 54, Hong Kong\",
        \"ip_address\": \"192.168.2.1\",
        \"global_unit_id\": \"0\",
        \"city\": \"Perugia\",
        \"branch\": \"Main\",
        \"spa_unit_nr\": \"1\",
        \"uid\": \"dev\",
        \"spa_website\": \"www.spaname.com\",
        \"continent\": \"Europe\",
        \"spa_phone\": \"+852 3847569\"
    }
}"


on JSONStringToRecord from input as text
    local input

    script objc
        use framework "Foundation"
        to unwrap()
            tell the current application to tell every reference in ¬
                (NSJSONSerialization's JSONObjectWithData:((NSString's ¬
                    stringWithString:input)'s dataUsingEncoding:4) ¬
                options:0 |error|:(reference)) to if it ≠ {} ¬
                then return its item 1 as {record, list, text}
        end unwrap()
    end script

    unwrap() in objc
end JSONStringToRecord
```

I took your JSON string output and just formatted it for easier reading.  But the variable `JSON` in the script above would, in your situation, look to get defined more like:

```
set JSONString to do shell script "<mycommand>"
set JSON to JSONStringToRecord from the JSONString
```

That ought to return the following record:

```
{
    |id|:"Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n",
    |data|:{
        spa_id:"0",
        os: "10.14.6",
        |name|: "Spa_Name",
        activity: "0",
        spa_email: "info@spa.com",
        serial: "C07XMRXWJYVW",
        nation: "Italy",
        spa_address: "Apliu Street 54, Hong Kong",
        ip_address: "192.168.2.1",
        global_unit_id: "0",
        city: "Perugia",
        branch: "Main",
        spa_unit_nr: "1",
        uid: "dev",
        spa_website: "www.spaname.com",
        continent: "Europe",
        spa_phone: "+852 3847569"
    }
}
```

which is formatted for readability, and would look more minified in *Script Editor*, ie:

```
{|id|:"Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n",|data|:{spa_id:"0",os:"10.14.6",|name|:"Spa_Name",activity:"0",spa_email:"info@spa.com",serial:"C07XMRXWJYVW",nation:"Italy",spa_address:"Apliu Street 54, Hong Kong",ip_address:"192.168.2.1",global_unit_id:"0",city:"Perugia",branch:"Main",spa_unit_nr:"1",uid:"dev",spa_website:"www.spaname.com",continent:"Europe",spa_phone:"+852 3847569"}}
```

This, clearly, looks very similar to the JSON string you started with, but it'll be clearer in *Script Editor* that it's not text, but rather a native data object, and the keys can now be accessed within AppleScript to isolate the values in the JSON record that you want.  Therefore:

```
|id| of JSON
```

would get you `"Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n"`.  And to get one of the more nested items, you would do this:

```
ip_address of |data| of JSON
```

which would get you `"192.168.2.1"`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be piped to the `cut` command, with double quotes as a field separator.

```
script | cut -d'"' -f3
```

Comment: Based on what's shown as returned in the OP, `-f3` is `:`, not `Ho1u8aA2p8jGuzEIZq8n`. Should be using: `-f4`